# Openshift : Unable to add secret using file

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

I am unable to add secret from file using below command :

## oc create -f /tmp/config.json

Output :  error: unable to decode "/tmp/config.json": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{

```
# cat /tmp/config.json 

    {
        "auths": {
            "my-repo-location" : {
                "auth": "ZTAxODE0W5V1yndNfoUdYWjRNtU="
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using `oc create -f` only works with manifest files. Try looking at `oc create secret -h` you should have some option to create a generic secret from a file.

Comment: Now that I'm at my desktop, you should be running `oc create secret generic config --from-file=/tmp/config.json`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@WillGordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6758654/will-gordon) comments you can use `oc create secret generic`, as shown in the example below:

```
$ cat config.json 
    {
        "auths": {
            "my-repo-location" : {
                "auth": "ZTAxODE0W5V1yndNfoUdYWjRNtU="
            }
        }
    }


$ oc create secret generic config --from-file=./config.json
secret/config created

$ oc get secret config -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.json: ICAgIHsKICAgICAgICAiYXV0aHMiOiB7CiAgICAgICAgICAgICJteS1yZXBvLWxvY2F0aW9uIiA6IHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICJhdXRoIjogIlpUQXhPREUwVzVWMXluZE5mb1VkWVdqUk50VT0iCiAgICAgICAgICAgIH0KICAgICAgICB9CiAgICB9Cg==
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2020-01-10T15:00:21Z
  name: config
  namespace: next
  resourceVersion: "46478941"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/next/secrets/config
  uid: ec4a4538-33b9-11ea-a9de-005056b7c210
type: Opaque
$
```

However, if creating a secret for accessing a Docker registry you can use the `docker-registry` option, as shown below:

```
oc create secret docker-registry SECRET_NAME \
       --docker-server=DOCKER-IMAGE-REPOSITORY \
       --docker-username=username@email.com \
       --docker-password="password" \
       --docker-email=username@email.com
```